# Mysterous PST corruption

Tags: microsoft-outlook, backup, microsoft-outlook-2016, file-corruption, pst

This is a tough one, am I allowed to offer beers for anyone who figures this out? If you are a computer repair enthusiast, this might be a fun one for you.

So I have a client who I do basic computer housekeeping for. He company uses Exchange with a low limit. For the last 10 years we have been moving her email to PST files for each year. These PST files are backed up.

About a month ago, she started having weird PST corruption errors, the PST fix wouldn't find anything wrong, outlook would restart, and work for a bit, and then come up with the errors again. She also started getting BSODs with memory errors. This lead me to run a bunch of diagnostics, eventually finding a bad stick of RAM.

Client needed a new computer anyway, so we got one. Set up, copied the PST files over, for almost a month, no problems.

Now the PST files are giving the SAME ERRORS on the new machine. At first it was only the most recent PST file from 2018 (which almost makes sense, because we actually copy files to it after the RAM went bad, so a corrupt email maybe?). But suddenly, ALL her PST files back to 2008 are now randomly sometimes not loading, and then saying they are corrupt and crashing outlook. The PST fix program never finds anything wrong with them!

I tried one of the backups, and GOT THE SAME ERROR.

The PST files are about 5GB to 20GB each with 10K to 200K emails

We are using outlook 2016, any updates in the last 3-4 months that could cause this?

I NEED to recover all the email out of the PST files. I have backups on backups on backups, but I'm trying to avoid dedicating a few months of my life into recovering and organizing a million or so emails. Looking for solutions to

A. Fix the PST files and stop these corruption errors.

B. Move the 1 million or so emails (10 years x 100K emails) to new PSTs file in a timely fashion

I am totally stumped on this. Outlook's error messages are cryptic, just a generic "corruption detected" and it lists the PST file, with no technical information, and don't give me a lot to work with.

THANK YOU FOR EVEN READING THIS.

Edit:

Please reserve judgement of using PST files. This is what my client wanted, I've been trying to push her to cloud based solutions for years, and she doesn't want it. "Don't Use PST files, they are bad" is not a solution to this issue.

Comment: As per your concern about the recent update, are you using click-to-run edition of Outlook? If this is the case, you may try reverting to an earlier version of Office 2016 to check the result: https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/2770432/how-to-revert-to-an-earlier-version-of-office-2013-or-office-2016-clic

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting?